# Divide monthly Internet volume allowance in 6 equal parts

Tags: internet-connection, bandwidth, multiple-users

Here I live with 5 other people and we are charged for a limited package.

Some use more and some less.

We want to divide our plan in 6 equal parts with user and password.

Is this possible?

Comment: You would need some kind of router or server that is capable of accounting for data usage and setting limitations. This is not possible in typical home networking situations.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a router that supports [DD-WRT](https://www.dd-wrt.com), there are a number of hotspot services (captive portals) you can use that would enable you to set up user accounts with traffic limiting.

This would allow you to create individual user accounts and set a specific limit, as well as a maximum bandwidth limit, for each.

See [here](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Captive_Portal) for further information from DD-WRT, and [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) for general information on captive portals.